# Why selenium "wait" is not consistent?

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have some webelement (text field) that I'm watching with `wait`, because I want to send some keys to it.

Tt looks something like this:

```
   val wait: WebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("invoice_supplier_name")))
        val supplierTextField: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("invoice_supplier_name"))
        supplierTextField.clear()
        supplierTextField.sendKeys(invoice.supplierName)
```

but sometimes it's ok and sometimes I get an error "element is not visible"

Does someone know why that could be?

thanks

Comment: How much time did you put in the `wait` initialization?

Comment: @guy 120 bro, edit the q

Comment: @Joe Maybe webdriver tells the truth and the element is not visible. Have you checked the web page? There could be some logic which sets the element visible if some pre-condition is fulfilled, e.g. user has clicked on that, has selected this, ....